# Update specific row in sql with php

Tags: php

I want to grab the specific $key and $id and insert it into my sql table, How can i get the $key and $id? If i just had 1 row, i could have solve it, but since its a while loop, do i have to do it other way?

I've tried with key as a start like this

```
if(isset($_POST['$key']))
```

When i press my button for update

```
if(isset($_POST['$key'])) {
            $dbhost = '*****';
            $dbuser = '*****';
            $dbpass = '*****';

        $conn = db2_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

        if(! $conn ) {
           die('Could not connect: ');
        }

        $postkey = $_POST['$key'];

        $sql = "UPDATE Products SET , KEY = $key, ID = $ID, DONE = 'X'  " ;
        $retval =  db2_exec( $conn, $sql);

        if(! $retval ) {
          die('Could not update data: ' . db2_stmt_errormsg());
        }
        echo "Updated data successfully\n";
        db2_close($conn); 
     }
```

Looping my tables

```
  while((db2_fetch_row($queryexe)){
     $key = db2_result($queryexe, 'KEY');
     $id = db2_result($queryexe, 'ID');
     $done = db2_result($queryexe, 'DONE');

    print("<td>$key</td>\n");
    print("<td>$id</td>\n");
    print("<td><button  name = '$key' type='submit' id = '$key' class='btn btn-default'>
    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-repeat'></i> Done
    </button></td>\n");
    print("</tr>\n");
```

Sorry if im unclear. I've tried my best

Comment: If you want to collect all the info in the loop try `$array[] = array( 'key' => db2_result($queryexe, 'KEY'), 'id' => db2_result($queryexe, 'ID'), 'done' => db2_result($queryexe, 'DONE') );` inside you while loop.

Comment: and how can i call it later? with same code as i did ?

Comment: You are rewriting the variable on each way round the loop.  When the loop finishes it will have the last values from the fetch only.  If you build the array and then `var_dump( $array );` you will see all the variables stored in the array.